# 3D Column chart not working with sliders in asp .net project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I got some errors while executing this code. And I dont know what was the reason. Iam trying 
    to implement 3D column chart in my project in asp .net .I got the chart but while adjusting the angles of 3D , ie
    Alpha Angle and Beta Angle the chart does nit redraing. Please check my code and help me.Please.
    My code : 
     
     
     
     
    
    $( document ).ready(function() {

```
//3D Column chart

var someFunction3DColumn=function () {
  $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
            margin: 75,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 15,
                beta: 15,
                depth: 50,
                viewDistance: 25
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: <%= yeardatabar%>
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
        labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            },
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'March',
                'April',
                'May',
                'June',
                'July'
            ]
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 25
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data:<%= field1%> 
        }]
        });
        function showValues() {
        alert("main");
        //$('#sliders').show();
        $('#R0-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha);
        $('#R1-value').html(chart.options.chart.options3d.beta);
        }

        // Activate the sliders
        $('#R0').on('change', function () {
            alert("alpha");
            chart.options.chart.options3d.alpha = this.value;
            alert(alpha);
            showValues();
            chart.redraw(false);
        });
        $('#R1').on('change', function () {
            alert("beta");
            chart.options.chart.options3d.beta = this.value;
            alert(beta);
            showValues();
            chart.redraw(false);
        });

        showValues();
    };

    if ($("#RadioButton1").is(":checked")) {$('#sliders').hide();
        someFunctionpie();
        }
    if ($("#RadioButton2").is(":checked")) {$('#sliders').hide();
        someFunctionbar();
        }
    if ($("#RadioButton3").is(":checked")) {$('#sliders').hide();
        someFunctionPyramid();
        }
    if ($("#RadioButton4").is(":checked")) {
        someFunction3DColumn();

        }    

    });


    <div id="sliders">
    <table>
        <tr><td>Alpha Angle</td><td><input id="R0" type="range" min="0" max="45" value="15"/> <span id="R0-value" class="value"></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Beta Angle</td><td><input id="R1" type="range" min="0" max="45" value="15"/> <span id="R1-value" class="value"></span></td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console (dev tools in the browser)?

Comment: @SebastianBochan  no error, but while adjusting slider no changes made

Comment: So problem is with not updating angles form slider, but not with priting chart generally

Comment: @SebastianBochan what i have to do.? please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to recreate [this demo](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-column-interactive). The problem is with your `chart` variable. In the above demo, different constructor is used:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({ ... });
```

While you are using:

```
$('#container').highcharts({ ... });
```

First one is creating chart and returning itself to variable. Second one is just creating chart inside element using jQuery. Change that, so you will have variable `chart`, and you will be able to set new options like `chart.options.chart.options3d.beta = this.value;`. Anyway, I'm pretty sure you have some errors in JS console..